# Como formatar o datetime no formato YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD no Django/Python?

Tags: python, django, datetime

Estou tendo uma dificuldade no Django em retornar o datetime no timezone local. No Django configurei `USE_TZ=True` e `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'`

Ao chamar `timezone.now()`, retorna o datetime com horário em utc, não sei qual o problema.

```
>>> print str(timezone.now().strftime('%z'))
+0000
```

Meu objetivo é formatar a datetime atual no utilizado pelo pagseguro, que é o '`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD'`, que seria ex:`'2015-02-26T01:40:000-03:00'`.

Como eu poderia resolver este problema no Django em relação ao timezone e retornar formatado conforme o pagseguro pede `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD'`?

Comment: Orion, Desculpe-me o comentário um tanto off-topic para a sua pergunta, mas vejo que você seguiu a proposta do Super User em português na Area 51, mas ainda não fez o commit. Então: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84282/super-user-em-portugues?referrer=4CYZyXbILZeSZMVw5WkVIw2

Comment: @Victor pensei que eu tivesse feito o commit, mas agora está feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para retornar o timezone conforme configurado no settings.py (`'America/Sao_Paulo'`), deve-se utilizar `timezone.localtime()`.

**Exemplo:**

```
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).isoformat()
2017-02-27T02:19:24.791673-03:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente é o formato que você quer.

```
import datetime
data = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
print data.isoformat()
# output '2015-02-27T00:20:53.351328'
```

E se você estiver procurando uma boa app para se comunicar com o pagseguro sugiro o pacote feito pelo Allisson Azevedo, o [django-pagseguro2](https://github.com/allisson/django-pagseguro2).

Se estiver usando o Django:

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.now().isoformat()
# output '2015-02-27T11:50:28.904180+00:00'
```

Comment: O formato de certa forma está correto, mas o resultado deve ser utilizando o timezone `America/Sao_Paulo`

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo usando timezone. Acho que quando o USE_TZ é verdadeiro o timezone.now() já suporta o timezone nas datas de acordo com a região no "settings.py". O Django já faz o tratamento nos templates.

Comment: Arthur, apenas `timezone.now()` não retorna o timezone local. Em relação ao `django-pagseguro2` já estava testando, só falta implementar o serviço de assinatura.